# UILabel in a custom UIButton that adjusted to the button's size with AutoLayout

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, autolayout, uilabel

I want to have UILabel inside a custom UIButton with constraints to the button size, but to adjust the leading and trailing constraints constants.
The idea is to make the UILabel a bit smaller than the button width (the label takes the font from the button and uses auto shrink).

Adding the relevant code in init with coder of my custom button results with unsatisfied constraints error.

```
label = UILabel(frame: bounds)
addSubview(label)

translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 10.0).isActive = true
label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

When I remove the "10.0" constant it works ok, but that idea is to give the label a different size, not the exact size of the button.
Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of additional label and constraints, try to set `button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0)`, and use the regular title of the button.

Instead of regular `UIButton`, create a subclass of it, and override the `intrinsicContentSize` method of the button to keep the possibility of autosizing:

```
class MyButton : UIButton {
   open override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        get {
            var ics = super.intrinsicContentSize
            ics.width = (ics.width < CGFloat(UINT16_MAX)) ? CGFloat(ceil(ics.width + self.titleEdgeInsets.left + self.titleEdgeInsets.right)) : ics.width
            ics.height = (ics.height < CGFloat(UINT16_MAX)) ? CGFloat(ceil(ics.height + self.titleEdgeInsets.top + self.titleEdgeInsets.bottom)) : ics.height
            return ics
        }
   }
}
```

If you need two labels (native button's `titleLabel` + your label), the approach is the same:

```
class MyButton : UIButton {
   var labelLeading : NSLayoutConstraint!
   var labelTrailing : NSLayoutConstraint!
   var labelTop : NSLayoutConstraint!
   var labelBottom : NSLayoutConstraint!
   let label = UILabel(frame: bounds)

   public override init(frame: CGRect) {
       super.init(frame: frame)
       internalInit()
   }

   public required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: coder)
       internalInit()
   }

   private func internalInit() {
       addSubview(label)
       /// !!! Important to make label to not translate its autoresizing mask, not the button
       label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

       labelLeading = label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 10.0)
       labelTrailing = label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
       labelTop = label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor)
       labelBottom  = label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor)
       NSLayoutConstraint.activate([labelLeading, labelTrailing, labelTop, labelBottom)
   }

   open override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        get {
            var ics = super.intrinsicContentSize
            ics.width = (ics.width < CGFloat(UINT16_MAX)) ? CGFloat(ceil(ics.width + self.titleEdgeInsets.left + self.titleEdgeInsets.right)) : ics.width
            ics.height = (ics.height < CGFloat(UINT16_MAX)) ? CGFloat(ceil(ics.height + self.titleEdgeInsets.top + self.titleEdgeInsets.bottom)) : ics.height
            return ics
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! However this won't achieve exactly what I need. I guess there's not enough context in my question, sorry, will try to explain: want to create a button with a label inside which has leading and trailing padding. The button will sit in a super view with fixed size, button can be smaller or equal to its superview. Button's text comes from config, thus its length can vary. I want the button to take its size from the label (intrinsicContentSize) but if the button will reach superview width the padding will shrink. Was meant to use constraints with priority lower than the ones to superview.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, had to add the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints also to the label:

```
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```